# Divide two into four and Divide two by four

Tags: grammaticality, mathematics

Why does "divide two into four" equal **two**, and "divide two by four" equal **one half**?

Correct if I am wrong, but this what I have learned recently.

Comment: One and a half ? Do you mean just one half?

Comment: What is the grammaticality issue here?

Comment: @simchona: Yes, fixed it.

Comment: @Kris: It's about the why in grammar.

Comment: As a AmE speaker from NE US, I have to say that I have a hard time recalling EVER hearing someone say "divide X into Y." I would not have been able to answer this question from someone without clarification of what they were asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OP's confusion arises because ["divide 2 into 4"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22divide%202%20into%204%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is an idiomatic usage meaning *perform a division operation, using 2 as the [divisor](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/divisor.html), and 4 as the [dividend](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/dividend.html)*.

> *symbolically...*
>    **4/2** = **2**
>
> *clearest verbal form...*
>    **divide 4 by 2, giving the answer 2**
>
> *idiomatic alternative...*
>    **divide 2 into 4, giving the answer 2**

It's *not* the same usage as *dividing a pizza into 4 [pieces]*, where you'd probably get **1/4** (a quarter) of a pizza as your share!

Comment: I have got conflicting answers for this question. Your answer seems to be in conflict with Jim's answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Noah: The other answerers either don't know of or forgot about the **idiomatic usage** referenced by my first link. I'm sure some people are unfamiliar with this usage because they've upvoted other answers, not mine. But you've obviously come across it or you wouldn't have asked the question. And obviously if *"divide two into four" = **two***, it can't be the same usage as *"divide a pizza into four"*, since that will give you four quarters, not two pizzas! Put a bounty on the question if you want some more people to think this one through and confirm that I'm right (or just believe me! :)

Comment: For me (an American) divide 2 into 4 is not the same as divide 2 by 4.  This one: divide 2 into 4 uses 2 as the divisor, as you say:   4/2 ... but divide 2 by 4 I take to mean use 4 as the divisor,  2/4 .

Comment: @GEdgar: You're quite right! I'm not sure how I managed to buy into what Jez had already answered at the time. Existing votes notwithstanding, I'll edit it to make more sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm wondering if you know a good reason why this interpretation is so common? It seems logical that "Divide 100 into 5" ought to be 20, based on ordinary usage in everyday language, but based on the common idiomatic usage for small numbers, it would bome out to 0.05.

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA: Well, there are two "different ways round" for performing division, and two common prepositions. So probably *part* of it is simply that if we know what *"divide 4 **by** 2"* means, we're happy to accept *"divide 4 **into** 2"* to designate the "opposite/inverse" operation (those prepositions can be "opposites" in other contexts, such as *"The snooker ball **passed by/went into** the pocket"*).

Comment: ...but mostly I think it comes from the early schooling context of learning long division, where the operation is invariably described as answering the question *"How many times does X go into Y?"*. In those early stages, no-one cares about awkward cases where the divisor is greater than the dividend.

Answer (score 6):

The expression of division using the word "into" comes from the form: "Two goes into four how many times?" Answer: two.
Dividing 2 by 4 means breaking(dividing) 2 into 4 equal parts ( 0.5 each).

You might think about it this way:
[image: No LaTeX in ELU!]

Have a look at this link for an example of "goes into":
http://www.themathpage.com/arith/divide-whole-numbers.htm

Comment: Is this a canonical rule? There are exceptions to this implication of *into* in the context of division.

Answer (score 5):

In *math* the term **divide** may have two different senses.

> 1) To use (a number) as a divisor. E.g: divided 5 into 35 = 7

5 is the divisor.

> 2) To subject (a number) to the process of division [by a divisior]. E.g:
>    If you divide 6 by 2, you get 3

2 is the divisor.

> 10 divided into 100 = 10
>   100 divided by 10 = 10

Please check [divide](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divide).

Comment: I suspect that if you actually asked on math.se they'd tell you they don't normally use the phrasing *"divide X into Y"*

Comment: @Fumble: On the Wikipedia page for long division ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division ... read down a ways and find this: "In this example, 37 is to be divided into 1260257."

Answer (score 3):

My experience of "divide [number] into [number]" was solely as regional spoken idiom. In different math textbooks used ca. 1965 in public schools both in suburban Seattle and on the South Side of Chicago, "40/8" was written out as "forty divided by eight." Outside Seattle it was said the same way. In Chicago, though, it was said "eight divided into forty." The discrepancy offers a good lesson about relying on numerical rather than verbal expressions when math is involved.

Answer (score 2):

"Divide 2 into 4" and "divide 2 by 4" seem semantically identical (2 / 4) to me; I don't recognize the former's meanining as 4 / 2.

Comment: I'm assuming "divide 2 into 4" has the meaning "remove 2 from 4", hence the answer is 2. Looks like _divide_ has the meaning _subtract_ here.

Comment: @user543101: That would be a seriously non-standard interpretation. Regardless of whether the preposition is *by* or *into*, subtraction would never be involved.