# Why is it "Divide by 0" instead of "Divide 0"?

Tags: expressions, terminology

When I read "by" it feels to me that the target to be divided is the number that comes before the 0, not the 0 itself. For example, "1 divided by 0", 1 is the target of the division, and 0 is what 1 will be divided by/into. However, this is invalid because

> "You can't divide [x] by 0"

I should be able to take a knife and choose to cut 1 apple INTO 0 pieces, which is equivalent to just discarding it, as there is none left. (Divide 1 apple BY 0 = 0)
1 whole apple is considered to be at least 1 piece.

Or I can try to cut 0 apples INTO 1 piece, but.. that's obviously not possible because you can't cut a non-existent apple. (Divide 0 apples BY 1 = undefined)

> "You can't divide 0 (by/into x)"

seems to make more sense to me than

> "You can't divide [x] by 0"

However, in reality this expression is not the case. So in reality, I can cut a non-existent apple into 1 piece and end up with 0 apples. But I can't actually cut 1 apple and divide it into 0 pieces?

Why is this?

Comment: To state that dividing 1 apple into 0 pieces "is equivalent to discarding it" displays a fundamental misunderstanding of mathematics; however, that's not an appropriate topic for this site. I should add that "to divide A _into_ B" is historically considered the same as "to divide B _by_ A".

Comment: @MattGutting, Agreed, and voting-to-close for that reason.

Comment: Might be a better question for Math.SE, but think of division as repeated subtraction. So 0/1 = "how many times can you subtract 1 from 0 before you get 0?" The answer is pretty obviously 0. On the other hand, 1/0 = "how many times can you subtract 0 from 1 before you get 0?" In this case, there's no answer (undefined/infinite) because you will never reach the target.

Comment: @Roger, While I appreciate you're only trying to help the OP, let's ***please not start*** the endless, pointless, enervating debate about the feasibility or interpretation of division by zero on EL&U.

Comment: This isn't really a math question, he wants to know why we use the preposition _by_, which is a language question.

Comment: Related: [***Divide two into four** and **Divide two by four***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58209/) (as per @Matt's comment). I don't exactly understand what OP's asking here, so I'm not sure if it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: @Barmar, no, OP explicitly says he understands and agrees with the preposition *by* indicating the denominator, *in all cases **except*** division by zero, where he has a .. novel arithmetical interpretation .. which prevents him from accepting the English usage in this case.

Comment: That makes no sense. For consistency, `x/y` should always be `divide x by y`, regardless of their values.

Comment: Ahhh... That was the problem. "into" is a reverse of "by" - this is where I was getting confused because I thought they had equivalent meaning. The linked topic helps solve my issue. I guess I wasn't really clear on the question as this topic seems to have been also interpreted as a mathematical question as well. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that *by* is used in those situations to signify the denominator.  That is, to let you know which number is being used to divide the quantity.  It is perfectly in line with the dictionary definition:

> *preposition* 1. identifying the agent performing an action.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&es_sm=93&q=define+by&oq=define+by&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0i20l2j0l7.4726.5571.0.6245.9.7.0.0.0.0.280.956.0j1j3.4.0.ecynfh...0...1.1.56.serp..5.4.954.3UycsJenEAc)

Answer (score 4):

For consistency, the phrase *divide X by Y* always means to perform the calculation represented by the equation `X/Y`. This is true regardless of the values of `X` and `Y`. So *divide X by 0* means `X/0`. Mathematics says that this is meaningless, so we say in English *you can't divide by 0.*

Comment: I'm not sure that answers everything. Why "divide by" and "multiply by" but not "add by" or "subtract by"?

Comment: @tobyink because addition is commutative. We actually do say "subtract by" sometimes. Division is not commutative (i.e. "the order of operations matters"), so we need to specify the numerator and denominator.

Comment: @Newb, multiplication is also commutative. Googling for "subtract by", the vast majority of results are for pages describing subtraction techniques - things like "subtract by counting backwards".

Comment: @tobyink ultimately it's because the divisor plays a different kind of role than the dividend, as the multiplier plays a different role than the multiplicand. In each case the first is a simple number, the second is a counter. In addition and subtraction there aren't different roles involved; the two addends/summands (in addition) and the subtrahend/minuend (in subtraction) are simple numbers.

Comment: @MattGutting, what part of [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) didn't you understand? The multiplier and multiplicand are completely interchangeable, just as the augend and addend are in cases of addition.

Comment: I understand and agree. Nevertheless, they're different *types* of numbers - this is why commutativity is so important. This is not, however, the place to go into a discussion of ring theory.