# what is the preposition equivalent to "divided by"

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

"times" is the preposition equivalent to "multiplied by".
what is the preposition equivalent to "divided by"?

Comment: In *Two **times** two equals four*, it's not a "preposition". OED defines the usage as a ***verb** - trans. Math. colloq. **To multiply** (a number).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: is the definition as a verb the *only* definition? I doubt it. It seems to me like a non-standard reanalysis, similar to using "verse" as a verb derived from the preposition "versus." As for the part of speech in standard language, I'd guess it originally derived from the noun "times," but it may very well have become a preposition--to test this, we could check if "one times x" or "one time x" is more common.

Comment: @sumelic: OED confirms ***times*** does indeed derive from the pluralised noun, but they only list it as a verb (with citations featuring ***timesed*** and ***timesing***). They have a separate entry for the other (capitalized) ***adjectival*** usage ***Times** attrib. Designating typefaces originally designed for use in The Times. Chiefly in Times New Roman, Times Roman,*  of which they say *Also as **noun**: a typeface of this kind.* No other parts of speech are mentioned in either entry. I've never encountered *one **time** x* in that context (only "one-time" = "former, ex-").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: weird! For me, it's definitely not always a verb; I could say "what is it times?" to mean "What is it multiplied by?" (and I'd never say "what does it time?).

Comment: @sumelic: If I were *forced* to rephrase *What is it multiplied by?*, I think I'd have to go for *What is it **timesed by**?* Your version sounds decidedly weird to me - would you also accept *What is it divided?* for the "reciprocal" version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent would be 'over'.

100/50=2 can be reasonably stated as one hundred over fifty equals two.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "into," as in "One hundred into fifty is two."

Comment: That's backwards, unfortunately. _Fifty into one hundred is two; fifty goes into one hundred twice_.

Comment: What @John said. But see [Divide two into four and Divide two by four](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58209/2637)

Comment: Oops; knew the order, typed too quickly. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DanielNelson, there should be an "edit" option under your answer, so that you can go back and fix it up.  :-)